# How can I pick up deadletters from azure service bus on .netcore 2 application?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have .net core application which needs to read dead letter queue of Azure ServiceBus.
Currently I see Windows.AzureServiceBus for .net full framework, but cannot find similar package for .netcore. 
Even links to an existing docs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MessageReceiver is providing that capability:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/src/Core/MessageReceiver.cs

```
// in my case ReceiveAndDelete, which will read the queue and delete it as well.
var receiver = new MessageReceiver(connectionString, $"{QueueName}/$deadletterqueue", ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);

var latestDeadLetters = await receiver.ReceiveAsync(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The new Azure Service Bus client library for .NET is part of the [Azure SDK for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net):

- [Azure Service Bus client library for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus).

you can find the related documentation here:

- [Azure Service Bus Messaging documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/)